# Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook : Unable to reach facebook tokenEndpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, owin

I'm trying to implement external authentication with facebook, in an asp.net web api2 project.

The version of the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` package i use is 3.0.1.

These steps works just fine:

- Redirect to the login facebook form for the external login
- The facebook callback to the backend api, with the authorization code (facebook login successful)

After that, the middleware should call the facebook tokenEndpoint,
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token, to get an access token.

But i get a socketException : *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed*

So i tried to mimic the call to the facebook tokenEndpoint (with `HttpClient.GetAsync`) in a console application.
I got a proxy error which i solved by specifying the proxy in the `WebRequestHandler`:

```
var proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler { Proxy = proxy });

//GetAsync OK with the use of the current system proxy
var result = RunSync(() => httpclient.GetAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"));
```

Finally i reported the proxy settings in the `FacebookAuthenticationOptions` in my application, but the error is still there.

I don't know why the call work in the console application, but not in the web application.
I tried to compare the HttpClient states between the two applications, but i found not much.

does someone have any clue what the cause of the problem could be?

Comment: Do you need a proxy server setting or so in there?

Comment: @BugFinder i'm not sure i underestand, but yes i need to pass through a proxy to access the Internet in my development environment. As i said, without the proxy the call from the console app is KO

Comment: You would have to either pick up proxy settings or allow users to enter them.

Comment: @BugFinder i said in the question that i set the proxy settings in the FacebookAuthenticationOptions, but that don't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` is not the same between my console application and my web application, despite the fact that no proxy was declared either in the app.config or in the web.config.

I read in the msdn that if no proxy was found in the application configuration,
`WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` would use the system default proxy.

That was the case for the console application, but not for the web application.
To use the system proxy in the web application, i had to specifically use `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()`.

That solved the access to the facebook tokenEndpoint in my development environment.

I have no clue where the proxy returned in my webapplication by `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` came from.